# ROC curve: how come I have an awful AUC (0.57) with a significant p value (<.001)?

Tags: p-value, roc, auc

I'm trying to identify a cut-off in a sample of values (areas): I'd like to state "if you encounter an area greater than... you can suspect a pathologic condition" or something like this. It's a case-control study, I have a sample of areas belonging to cases and a sample belonging to controls: there is quite an overlap between cases and controls within the smaller areas, but when it comes to higher values of areas, only the case group displays them (image). 
I don't understand why I can't find a good cut-off value to discern between my two populations when the difference between them (calculated with nonparametric Mann-Whitney test) is highly significant (p<.001)...[image: example of my two populations: overlap with smaller values, no overlap with higher values]

Comment: The p-value is a measure of the strength of evidence (how convincing is the evidence that there is a difference between the groups?). That doesn't tell you the effect size (how large, meaningfully, is the difference between the two groups?) and therefore how easy to separate they are. This is visible in your graph - while it is seems clear that one distribution has a higher average than the other, the two do overlap considerably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let me generate some data

```
set.seed(123)
a <- rnorm(20, 0, sd=1)
b <- c(rnorm(30, 0, sd=1), rnorm(10, 3, sd=1))
x <- c(a, b)
x <- x-min(x)
x <- x/max(x)
y <- c(rep(0,20), rep(1,40))
plot(jitter(y), jitter(x), ylab='score', xlab='group')
```

[image: recreation of OP's data]

and some plots

```
library(ROCR)
pred <- prediction(x, y)
auc <- performance(pred, 'auc')
print(auc)
auc_plot <- performance(pred, "tpr", "fpr")
tpr_plot <- performance(pred, "tpr")
fpr_plot <- performance(pred, "fpr")
prec_plot <- perf <- performance(pred, "prec")

par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(auc_plot, colorize=T, main="ROC curve")
plot(tpr_plot)
plot(fpr_plot)
plot(prec_plot)
```

[image]

In this case AUC is 0.58375. But ROC is a trade of between true positive rate and false positive rate, since you have such a big overlap, you will never have good trade-off between true positive and false positive value. Therefore, there is no apparent threshold to choose, and in general your model looks horrible. ROC is however not telling the whole story and you can get threshold based on other measures. 0.65 seems reasonable in my case

Comment: Well thank you @user2173836 for your work and your advice... Unfortunately I don't get the plots you made because I know just a little about statistics (I'm a med student), but I'll look into it! Anyway, now I see more clearly the faults and limitations of my model ;) Thanks

Comment: The point is, that because of the overlap, you will never catch enough forum your cases group, without getting too much false positives, and therefore your ROC will be small. But if you look at how certain you are that the the sample predicted as case, is really case (precision) you will get much better outcome for some threshold values. Just look at what those variables mean, for example here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity and you will be fine (and if it solves your problem, accept the answer :))